# Cordova Build Error for Android

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, cordova-cli

I have been running through the Cordova tutorial for installation and creating a first app.  After spending the last few hours trying to figure this out I have pretty much reached a dead end.  I'm currently running Ubuntu and trying to build on Android 4.0.0.

I have all of the files listed in the error below already.  In addition to this error I get 3 consecutive popups for non-existent files that say:

> "Cannot find file '/home/prawg/workspace/hello/list'"
>
> "Cannot find file '/home/prawg/workspace/hello/targets'"
>
> "Cannot find file '/home/prawg/workspace/hello/--compact'"

Here is the error:

> [Error: Please install Android target: "android-22".
>
> Hint: Open the SDK manager by running: /usr/local/bin/android
>   You will require:
>
> 1. "SDK Platform" for android-22
> 2. "Android SDK Platform-tools (latest)
> 3. "Android SDK Build-tools" (latest)]
>
> ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /home/prawg/workspace/hello/platforms/android/cordova/build:
>
> Command failed with exit code 2
>
> You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
>
> Error: /home/prawg/workspace/hello/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
>
> at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:131:23)
>
> at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
>
> at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
>
> at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:833:5)

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after spending hours trying to figure this out I finally reached a solution.

When I installed Android I did it through the Android Studio download.  After installing, I went to the SDK Manger in the UI and updated the 3 files listed in the error above.  For some reason this did not update in the SDK where my $ANDROID_HOME path was set to which was /home/prawg/Android/Sdk

The solution is as follows:

I went to the $ANDROID_HOME directory - /home/prawg/Android/Sdk through the terminal and used the following command:

```
tools/android update sdk --no-ui
```

From the terminal all of the updates were installed and when I typed the build command for Android there was no issue.

Maybe someone with more Android experience can elaborate on why this is the case?

Comment: this installs every version of android by the looks of it?

Comment: Definitely installed all versions for me and did not solve my issue.